# Passing C# Guid list to SQL Server table type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to pass 2 Guid's to a SQL Server table type and then execute a stored procedure.

My table type looks like this

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Ident] AS TABLE
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Id2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

My C# code looks like this. I am trying to pass id to id and value to id2 in SQL Server table type `[Ident]` and return `[type]` from the stored procedure.

I get this error

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String[] to a IEnumerable`1.'

How do I pass these guids in the method to the table type?

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String connectionString = "connection string.....";

            List<Guid> id = new List<Guid>();
            id.Add(Guid.Parse("guid....."));

            List<Guid> Value = new List<Guid>();
            Value.Add(Guid.Parse("guid......."));

            Console.WriteLine(GetValue2(id, Value, connectionString));
        }

        public static List<ItemTest> GetValue2(List<Guid> Id, List<Guid> Value, String connectionString)
        {
            List<ItemTest> items = new List<ItemTest>();

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("stored procedure....", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter tvpParameter = new SqlParameter();
                tvpParameter.ParameterName = "@id";
                tvpParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
                tvpParameter.Value = (new string[] { "Id", "Id2" });
                tvpParameter.TypeName = "[dbo].[Ident]";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(tvpParameter);

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine((int)rdr["type"]);
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            return items;
        }
    }

    public class ItemTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Stock Item ID 
        /// </summary>
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Item number as on channel
        /// </summary>
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have two parameters in the Stored Procedure, you should pass the parameters one by one.

Comment: GUIDs make *horrible* keys that guarantee constant table fragmentation. If you really-really want to use GUIDs as keys, use SQL Server's `NEWSEQUENTIALID` function to generate the GUID field's default value, don't generate it on the client

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) says you can make your parameter value a datatable (among other things), rather than a string array, perhaps something like:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Guid));
dt.Columns.Add("Id2", typeof(Guid));
dt.Rows.Add(guid1, guid2);
tvpParameter.Value = dt;
```

I'm not really sure what's going on with your `List<T>` all over the place; this example is for one pair of guids, `guid1` and `guid2`. If you have multiple, put more guid pairs in the datatable (more rows)

Answer (score 0):

Might be late answer. Hoping it would help for future visitors

```html
Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityClassName>("stored procedure name @params, ....",
CreateGuidList("params name",  list<guid>)).ToList();
```

```html
public SqlParameter CreateGuidList(string paramname, List<Guid> ids){
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Guid));
            if (ids != null)
            {
                foreach (var id in ids)
                {
                    table.Rows.Add(id);
                }
            }
            return new SqlParameter(name, table) { TypeName = "GuidList" };
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).